# Angular: How to login user with JWT and than get user info?

Tags: angular, http, jwt, observable

I have an Angular project with JWT login to backend, after I get a token I want to make call backend to get user info, this is my code inside authentication service:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWT+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWTInput+json',
    })
  };

  const body = { WTInput: {
                          username: username,
                          password: password
                      }
                  };


  return this.http.post<EzJwt>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/token/jwt`, body, headers)
      .pipe(map(token => {
        //Here I want to call getEzUserInfo() and get user info

      }));
}


getEzUserInfo(): Observable<EzUser> {
      const headers = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ez.api.SessionInput+json',
          'Accept': 'application/vnd.ez.api.User+json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        })
      };
      return this.http.get<EzUser>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/users/14`, headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use finalize in your pipe like this:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWT+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWTInput+json',
    })
  };

  const body = { WTInput: {
                          username: username,
                          password: password
                      }
                  };


  return this.http.post<EzJwt>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/token/jwt`, body, headers)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.getEzUserInfo()
        })
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use concatMap like so:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWT+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ez.api.JWTInput+json',
    })
  };

  const body = { WTInput: {
                          username: username,
                          password: password
                      }
                  };


  return this.http.post<EzJwt>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/token/jwt`, body, headers)
      .pipe(concatMap(_ => this.getEzUserInfo()));
}
```

Comment: this code works but where I can place the "localStorage.setItem('access_token', jwt['JWT']._token);" after the authentication post?

Comment: You can call a tap(jwt=> localStorage.setItem('access_token', jwt['JWT']._token)) before calling concatMap, that should work.

Comment: return this.http.post<EzJwt>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/token/jwt`, body, headers).tap(jwt=> localStorage.setItem('access_token', jwt['JWT']._token)).pipe(concatMap(_ => this.getEzUserInfo()));

VisualCode say:
Property 'tap' does not exist on type 'Observable<EzJwt>'

Comment: you can write my code because the angular syntax it's very difficult

Comment: So it should be inside the pipe call like this:
.pipe(tap(jwt=> localStorage.setItem('access_token', jwt['JWT']._token)),
    concatMap(_ => this.getEzUserInfo()));

Answer (score 0):

I modify my code with this:

```
return this.http.post<EzJwt>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/token/jwt`, body, headers).pipe(
      tap(jwt => localStorage.setItem('access_token', jwt['JWT']._token)),
      concatMap(_ => this.getEzUserInfo())
    );
```

but I need to add this two lines of code when getEzUserInfo() it's return success:

```
this.userSubject.next(user);
this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
```